# WebObject.getAttribute("title") does not work in python. Any idea about it?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to read text from the tool tip of a web element in Python. Working on automation testing of UI in selenium.

Comment: It would help to show some code - the relevant HTML, the code you tried and the exact result (ie is "does not work" an exception or something else)?

Comment: This is the HTML piece:  

<span title="TKA - ThyssenKrupp AG" class="blue-c6" id="yui_3_14_0_1_1410520580894_8223"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="yui_3_14_0_1_1410520580894_8222">TKA</a></span>       

This is what I tried:    

self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.blue-c6').getAttribute("title")      

This gives error as:     

'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'       

Note:    
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.blue-c6').text gives the right value (i.e., TKA).

Comment: I know this question seems trivial but I've +1'd it because selenium docs are somewhat hard to follow and searching sometimes gives examples in Java or C# that are somewhat different. It often isn't clear exactly what will work in the various versions

Answer (score 10):

Given that you are using Python, there is no `getAttribute` method. As seen in the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute), it should be `get_attribute`:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.blue-c6').get_attribute('title')
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for the information and your prompt help.